# ClientSideValidations with Cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, client-side-validation, cocoon-gem

I'm using client_side_validations(3.2.0.beta.3) and client_side_validations-formtastic (2.0.0.beta.3)
On the form I have nested fields that is added with help of the cocoon gem (https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) and validations throw an error 'validators is undefined'
I think that problem is that FromBuilder for nested fields from cocoon is not known by client_side_validations. Did anybody have this problem and find out solution?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I've looked at this in depth and there doesn't seem to be an functioning solution for the combination of 1) a simplified form builder (simple_form or formtastic), 2) nested forms (nested_form or cocoon), and 3) client side validations.

I tried to get this [demo](https://github.com/umerkulovb/formtastic-cocoon-client-side-validations-demo) working, but to no avail.

Discussions [here](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/56) and [here](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/71) seem to suggest that there are people working on a solution, though it doesn't seem like there is one right now.

Just hoping that this saves someone some time in the future.

Comment: Hi Link_er, I actually managed to get it the cocoon with client side validations on nested fields mostly working. The mistake I had been making was not including the files in my application.js. Did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: What files didn't you include?

Comment: Hi Sherwin, the links you provide are a result of the discussion between Link_er and me in an attempt to get this working. I am very interested in hearing what you needed to do to get it to work. Also there was a new release of client-side validations which might have helped. I haven't had a look at it again though.

Answer (score 0):

add this JS somewhere and it all should work:

```
$(form_selector).on('cocoon:after-insert', function() {
    $(form_selector).enableClientSideValidations();
});
```